# How to suppress "Cannot resolve corresponding JNI function" in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-native-interface

I am creating a native method in Android Studio which is registered using RegisterNatives in JNI_OnLoad when the library is loaded. The problem is that I want to encrypt the method name and signature strings, but if I do that Android Studio doesn't let me compile the app because of this error: "Cannot resolve corresponding JNI function Java_my_app_Native_initializeApplication."
How can I suppress this?

Comment: But if you suppress that, and get a build, it simply won't work because the java's `native` methods won't correspond to the JNI methods which invoke the C/C++ methods. Unless you've come up with a way to solve that, I think this error is helping you and saving you tremendous time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking the quick fix button gave me a pop up to add a `@Suppress("KotlinJniMissingFunction")` annotation to either the class or the file. You can keep it there or move it to all your methods, eg:

```
@Suppress("KotlinJniMissingFunction")
external fun initializeApplication()
```

or

```
@Suppress("KotlinJniMissingFunction")
class Native : AppCompatActivity() {
...
}
```

The equivalent annotation for Java is `@SuppressWarnings("JavaJniMissingFunction")`.